# PHPMailer send multiple emails fails

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm having a problem with PHPMailer. I'm creating a page for job applications for a company. There is a form, which the applicant fills, and the form data is sent to the HR. Then there must be an automatic response from the server to the applicant which thanks the application. The first email to the HR is sent, but the second is not. The code is:

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->From = "admin@bav.hu";
$mailer->FromName = "Báv gyakornoki jelentkezés";
$mailer->AddAddress("dudas.krisztian@nerddevelopments.com", "the subject");
$mailer->isHTML(true);
$mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mailer->Subject = "Báv gyakornoki regisztráció";
$body = "The body with the form data to HR";
$mailer->Body = $body;
$mailer->AddAttachment($cv_path, $_FILES['cv']['name']);
$mailer->AddAttachment($motivation_letter_path, $_FILES['motivation']['name']);
$success = $mailer->send();
//this email gets sent
$autoresponse = new PHPMailer();
$autoresponse->From = "gyakornok@bav.hu";
$autoresponse->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$autoresponse->AddAddress($email);
$autoresponse->Subject = "This is an automatic message, please don't answer it";
$body = "This is the automatic response to the applicant";
$autoresponse->body = $body;
$autoresponse_sent = $autoresponse->send();
//this email won't get sent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change**

```
$autoresponse->body = $body;
```

**to**

```
$autoresponse->Body = $body;
```

Comment: Thank you, I also noticed it lately... Damn typos... I was so stupid